# php fatal error handler... failing with no error_get_last() set

Tags: php

I have been using a `fatal_handler()` function that I expanded on for over a  year now but for some reason I now have random errors popping up in the `error_log` file on the server and triggering the notification.  Previous to a little while ago it was working fine.

The errors seem to come from the array `$error` which is suppose to be set by `error_get_last()`.  With that, I am even unsure why the error event is firing.  Any of my logs that the function creates are empty.  It doesn't give me any specific page causing the error, just the function itself.

The $notice->rMsg saves the notification in a session variable and then displays anything in that session variable the next page load.  Sometime I have 10 or 20 of these notifications popping up when I shouldn't.  The page still loads, I am not redirected to the system logs, and I can continue on but the errors still keep coming.  I do not know what is wrong but hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to look.

```php
        if(empty($public)) {
            register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler" );
        }
        elseif($public) {
            register_shutdown_function( "fatal_handler_public" );
        }


        /* Array to correspond error numbers to the text. */
        $log_errors = array(
                "E_ERROR" => 1,
                "E_WARNING" => 2, 
                "E_PARSE" => 4, 
                "E_CORE_ERROR" => 16,
                "E_USER_ERROR" => 256, 
                "E_USER_WARNING" => 512, 
                "E_USER_NOTICE" => 1024);

        /*  1. PHP Fatal Error Handler
        --------------------------
            Handles PHP Fatal errors... hopefully.
            */

        function fatal_handler() {
            global $data,$path,$notice,$user,$log_errors,$db,$admin;
                        
            $errfile = "Unknown File";
            $errstr  = "Shutdown Initiated";
            $errno   = E_CORE_ERROR;
            $errline = 0;
            $error = error_get_last();
            if($error !== NULL) {
                $errno   = $error["type"];    // Line 368
                $errfile = $error["file"];    // Line 369
                $errline = $error["line"];    // Line 370
                $errstr  = $error["message"]; // Line 371
            }
            
            $error["user"] = $user["id"];
            
            if(in_array($errno,$log_errors)) {
                $error["date"] = time();
                if(strpos($errstr,'mysqli') > 0) {
                    $type = "MySQL";
                }
                else {
                    $type = "PHP";
                }
                $admin->record('@C@ encountered a '.$type.' Fatal Error at line '.$errline.' of '.$errfile.'.');
                $log_file = $path["full"]."/system/logs/$type.log";
                if(file_exists($log_file)) {
                }
                else {
                    touch($log_file);
                }
            // another way to call error_log():
                error_log(json_encode($error)."\r\n", 3, $log_file);
                $_SESSION[$data["license"]]["error"]["shutdown"] = json_encode($error);

                if($_SESSION[$data["license"]]["userid"]==1) {
                    $disabled = "<script>$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on('click','#view-logs', function() { window.location = '/system/logs/'; }); });</script>";
                    $goto = '/system/logs/';
                } else { $goto = '/dashboard/'; $disabled = "<script>$(document).ready(function() { $(document).on('click','#view-logs', function() { alert('Sorry, log files are only accessible by the System Super Admins.'); }); }); </script>"; }
                $notice->rMsg($notice->danger("There was a fatal ".$type." error which shut down the software.  We have logged this error to our logs for review however, we also ask you submit a support request.<br>
                    Details included in the report are the error details, your e-mail and name, the date and time. By submitting a support request this will help us find and fix the error faster.<br><br>
                    <button class='btn btn-lg btn-danger' id='submit-support-request'>Submit Support Request</button> <a class='btn btn-lg btn-default' href='#' id='view-logs'>View System Logs</a>".$disabled,"FATAL ERROR"));
                $protocol = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_SCHEME);
                $urlParts = explode('/', str_ireplace($protocol, '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
                $url = '//'.$data["sub-domain"].'.'.$data["domain"].'/'.$urlParts[1].'/'.$urlParts[2].'/';
                //header("Location: ".preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]));
                //Sent to Dashbord for Fatal Errors.
                    //header("Location: /dashboard/");
                    header("refresh:1;url=".$goto);
            }
        }
```

**LOG FILE**

```
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: line in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 370
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 371
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:18:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 368
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 369
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: line in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 370
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 371
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:19:27 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 368
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 369
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: line in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 370
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 371
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:20:22 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: type in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 368
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 369
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: line in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 370
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: message in /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php on line 371
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP Stack trace:
[09-Jan-2022 01:21:28 America/Regina] PHP   1. fatal_handler() /home/public_html/dsm/class/autoload.class.php:0
```

**UPDATE: January 9, 2022 11:40am**

It appears the script below is causing the "error" and the event to fire.  This is for an administration system which if the user is not active it places a lock screen after so many minutes requiring a password again.  This script keeps the session active so the lock screen continues to work for a couple hours instead of loosing the session and requiring a full login again.  If the browser resets the session it will redirect back to the main login screen.

This is called via ajax every couple minutes or so; which is why when I reload the page I get multiple error notices produced by the `fatal_handler()`.  However, I don't know why php is registering a shutdown as the error_get_last() is still blank.

```
/* Session Expire */
include("../class/autoload.class.php");

if(isset($_SESSION[$data["license"]]["userid"])) {
    $_SESSION[$data["license"]]["userid"] = $_SESSION[$data["license"]]["userid"];
    $_SESSION[$data["license"]]["session-date"] = date("F j, Y g:i:s A");
    echo "Session Refresh:\n--------------------\nUser ID: ".$_SESSION[$data["license"]]["userid"]."\nSession Time: ".$_SESSION[$data["license"]]["session-date"];
}
else {
    echo 'redirect';
}
```

Comment: fatal_handler is registered as a shutdown function (not an error handler), so error_get_last will return null in most cases. If you recently added  this line `$error["user"] = $user["id"];`, I think it's the problem.

Comment: As in the title it is a "fatal error handler" so it does handle the fatal errors, those that cause PHP to crash.  Instead of displaying a blank screen it redirects the user that doesn't know any better and gives them a nice warning; also logging the error for myself to view and diagnose.  For the most part my users do not see this message as I try to clear and diagnose anything that might cause it before they get there but this is baffling me as to why it's triggering with no error.  It doesn't redirect me.

Comment: Figured why it doesn't redirect me.  It's because it's happening in the background on an page touched via AJAX.  I have updated my question to include this as I don't know why php is registering a shutdown and calling the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, [`register_shutdown_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) registers a handler to run every time PHP "shuts down" - that is, **at the end of every request**, regardless of whether it's ending "normally" or after an error.

It's therefore up to you, *inside the handler function*, to detect whether the shutdown was due to a fatal error or not. The common trick with this is to look at the last "error", which might better be termed "diagnostic", because it includes Warnings, Notices, and Deprecation messages. If there *was* a fatal error, we can expect it to be the last thing that happened before the shutdown handler is called, so if we *immediately* call [`error_get_last`](https://www.php.net/error_get_last), we should get the information about it.

Let's trace through some key parts of your function:

```
// if nothing else sets $errno, assume that every request ends in a fatal error
// that's probably not a sensible assumption (unless your code is really bad )
$errno = E_CORE_ERROR; 
// ...
// retrieve error information - will be NULL if no diagnostic has occurred
$error = error_get_last();
// add a 'user' key to the error information
// this doesn't check if $error was NULL, so if it was, it will turn it into an array
$error["user"] = $user["id"];
// now check if $error is NULL - but it never will be, because of the line above
if($error !== NULL) {
    // take the error type from the array
    // if it was actually NULL, this won't be set, so we'll get an $errno of NULL
    // that's what's causing all the Notices in your logs
    $errno   = $error["type"];
    // ...
}
// after gathering the error information, decide whether to log it
if(in_array($errno,$log_errors)) {
```

Luckily, the default of `E_CORE_ERROR` and the broken check for `NULL` cancel each other out, so that if there was no error returned from `error_get_last()`, we are checking `in_array(NULL,$log_errors)`, which will be false.

However, looking at `$log_errors`, which is defined as a global variable earlier:

```
$log_errors = array(
                "E_ERROR" => 1,
                "E_WARNING" => 2, 
                "E_PARSE" => 4, 
                "E_CORE_ERROR" => 16,
                "E_USER_ERROR" => 256, 
                "E_USER_WARNING" => 512, 
                "E_USER_NOTICE" => 1024);
```

Apart from the slightly odd decision to hard-code the numbers rather than use the actual constants, note that this includes both Warnings and Notices. These can happen at any time, and there might have been a dozen Notices already logged on the page, but `error_get_last()` will just contain the most recent if no other diagnostics happened afterwards. It's therefore not relevant to look for these inside the shutdown handler - you just want to spot things that would cause a shutdown.

**A Notice or Warning will not cause a script to exit early, so it makes no sense to log them in a shutdown handler, which will only see whichever happened to come last.** They will already have been logged based on your [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) settings, or you can use [set_error_handler](https://www.php.net/set_error_handler) to have custom handling of *all* of them.

We can massively simplify the function by checking for fatal errors (and *only* fatal errors) straight away, and just ending the function if none are found:

```
function fatal_handler() {
    $fatal_errors = [
        E_ERROR,
        E_USER_ERROR,
        E_CORE_ERROR,
        E_COMPILE_ERROR,
        E_PARSE,
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR
    ];
    $error = error_get_last();
    if($error === NULL || !in_array($error['type'], $fatal_errors)) {
       // Clean shutdown. Nothing to do.
       return;
    }
    // Fatal error detected - proceed with logging based on value of $error
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting concept and approach.  FYI you are missing a bracket on ` if($error === NULL || !in_array($error["type"], $fatal_errors) { ` (IE: ` if($error === NULL || !in_array($error['type'], $fatal_errors)) { ` ).  I did move the ` $error["user"] = $user["id"]; ` after the `NULL` check; however it didn't stop it (and I forgot to update that part of my question, sorry). 

I do plan on updating my function to use some of what you proposed and see what happens.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine It's really exactly the same "concept" as your existing function; the early return is the equivalent of putting everything inside `if($error !== NULL && in_array($error['type'], $fatal_errors)) { ... }`, which is just your two if statements combined onto one line, so that lines like `$error["user"] = $user["id"];` can't accidentally sneak in between. The more important problem with your current function is that **you are logging Notices and Warnings**, which will **never** be the cause of the shut down, so logging them here makes no sense.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine Looking back, I see that the importance of that may have been lost among the other problems I was pointing out, so I've added a bold line to the answer, because even if you fix everything else, your function will not make any sense if it doesn't distinguish between fatal errors and notices.

Comment: I do appreciate the help!!  Now, while the Notice and Warning are listed in the array of possible "errors" to log since they are never the cause of the shutdown, they are never actually logged. The array is a global array which allows the corresponding error number to be associated with Constant name in a string for other functions and log pages.

The reason I programmed the numbers and names into an array is because the manual for `error_get_last()` specifies it returns the error number and not the constant.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine They are never the cause of the shutdown, but you are not retrieving them with `error_get_cause_of_shutdown()`, you are retrieving them with `error_get_last()` - whatever the last "error" is, it will be returned. Perhaps the key that you're still missing is that **shutdown does not mean fatal error**; every single request to your server results in a "shutdown" when everything is finished. Unless your code is perfect, some of those requests _will_ have raised Notices and Warnings at some point, and `error_get_last()` will return the most recent one.

Comment: @DawsonIrvine As for constants vs numbers, you have another misconception - constants aren't a _type of value_, they are way of _labelling_ values, just like variables. So if you write `echo E_USER_WARNING;` it will display `512`, because 512 is the _value_ pointed at by that constant. The idea is that _you don't need to know the number_, because you can just reference it by name - if the number returned by `error_get_last()` matches `E_USER_WARNING`, you know that it's a user-emitted warning, _without having to look at what number that actually is_.

Comment: I think I understand now. *facepalm*  If I have a Notice or Warning sometime throughout the script it will still log it upon shutdown, since, in web terms, it shuts down once the page is loaded and that was the 'last error'.  That would explain why I would sometime have a PHP Notice or Warning pop up in my log but not all of them.

Also, you're right, I was thinking of constants all wrong for this project.  I know I can assign values to constants myself to use later on just like these constants have the number values assigned to them.  *another facepalm*